# Django Many to One Model Relation

Tags: django, django-models

When I creating my django models I stacked up at this point.

Now, I have a model like this:

```
class My_Files(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file_size = models.IntegerField()
    ... etc ...
```

And these files must have a relation with file which it can be uploaded to my server or http link to another server. How can I handle this relation?

Thank You

Comment: You can use URLField (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/) to store the link to the file stored in the other server

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [django-uploadify](https://github.com/tstone/django-uploadify/wiki) it helps you, in the manner such that, whenever a new file is uploaded a signal is fired with the file data, you can use that signal to populate your models. It is much easier than writing a custom signal for yourself. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
class My_Files(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file_size = models.FloatField()
    file_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    file_locate = model.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

You also should write many methods in `views` and `forms` to fill any needed fields.